# Find the CDF and use it to find all the medians

Tags: probability, means, cumulative-distribution-functions

Show that for every $p$, $0\leq p\leq 1$, the function $f(x)$ = $p\sin(x) +(1-p)\cos(x)$, $0\leq x \leq \pi/2 $, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, is a density function. Find its CDF and use it to find all the medians.

I was able to prove it a density function and also was able to get the CDF which is 
$(p +\sin(x) -p(\sin(x) + \cos(x))$ ; $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$ and $1$ for $ x\geq \pi/2$ and $zero$ elsewhere.
(I hope I am correct)

I don't understand the last part. What do they mean by finding all the medians?
I tried putting the CDF equal to $0.5$. I still can't figure it out. I have an equation with two variable $p$ and $x$. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your CDF is fine. Setting the CDF to $1/2$ is the right approach. Maybe make the substitution $t = \sin x$ and $\sqrt{1-t^2} = \cos x$, and solve for $t$ (with $p$ fixed), which amounts to solving a quadratic equation. You will get a different median for each value of $p$ (that is, the solution will be in terms of $p$).

Comment: Thank you. I got it now.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444383/find-the-cdf-and-use-it-to-find-all-the-medians.

Comment: I still can't solve it bu even using the substitution. I am not getting a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Mathematica, I found the solutions to $p + \sin x - p(\sin x+\cos x)=\frac12$ to be
$$
\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 p \left(\sqrt{p^2 (4 (p-1) p+3)}+2 (p-1) p\right)-\sqrt{p^2 (4 (p-1) p+3)}}{p (4 p-3)}\right)
$$
and
$$
\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{p^2 (4 (p-1) p+3)}-2 p \left(\sqrt{p^2 (4 (p-1) p+3)}-2 (p-1) p\right)}{p (4 p-3)}\right).
$$